# HTML How do I change my address bar icon?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what code do I use to change my address bar icon? I have my 16x16.png file ready. It is in the same folder as my home.html on my desktop.

Also for the folder being on my desktop, what do I use as the directory? I quite do not understand what to put.

Answer (score 0):

You need .ico file normally named as "favicon.ico" and if the existing one is also have same name "favicon.ico" you can just upload and it should be done.